# On devices with API level below 21, a full build is required if the app is not running?

Tags: android

App crushes when running the project and I get this message;

**Performing full build and install:On devices with API level below 21, a full build is required if the app is not running.**

My build.gradle looks like this;

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.olal.employeemanagementsystem"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I am using android version 4.3, api level 18 for this project.

please help.

Comment: what is the problem? what is happening if that message is displayed?

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy ,when i run the project ,it displays that message and the app crushes.I am using android version 4.3 ,api level 18

Comment: Sounds like an instant-run issue. Check to make sure your gradle plugin is set to 2.0 or higher to support  `minSdkVersion 15`

Comment: @Olal what is the error you are getting? can you post your logcat when your app crashes?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell , I am using Gradle version 2.2.3

Comment: @ChrisStillwell,

5:09:09 PM Gradle build finished in 9s 201ms  
5:12:45 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
5:12:49 PM Gradle build finished in 4s 436ms
5:13:10 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
5:13:12 PM Gradle build finished in 1s 680ms
5:13:14 PM Performing full build and install:
           On devices with API level below 21, a full build is required if the app is not running.